# Riemannian homogeneous compact solvmanifold is a torus

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups

A solvmanifold is a manifold $ M $ which admits a transitive action by a solvable Lie group. A Riemannian homogeneous space is a Riemannian manifold whose isometry group acts transitively.

Let $ M $ be a compact solvmanifold which is Riemannian homogeneous with respect to some metric $ g $ . Can we conclude that $ M $ is a torus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A Riemannian homogeneous manifold has fundamental group with finite commutator subgroup.

[Transitive action by compact Lie group implies almost abelian fundamental group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4321106/transitive-action-by-compact-lie-group-implies-almost-abelian-fundamental-group)

But the fundamental group of a solvmanifold is torsion free so a finite subgroup is trivial. Thus a Riemannian homogeneous solvmanifold has abelian fundamental group. Since the fundamental group of a compact solvmanifold is always torsion free and finitely generated then we can conclude the fundamental group is $ \mathbb{Z}^n $. But it is a theorem of Auslander that a compact solvmanifold is determined up to diffeomorphism by it's fundamental group. So a compact Riemannian homogeneous solvmanifold must be a torus.

Indeed this result generalizes from solvmanifolds to all aspherical manifolds that are compact Riemannian homogeneous see

[Riemannian homogeneous aspherical iff flat torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4382864/riemannian-homogeneous-aspherical-iff-flat-torus)

Also note that the linked question proves something much stronger: a Riemannian homogeneous aspherical closed manifold is not just diffeomorphic to a torus but in fact the original homogeneous Riemannian metric must have been flat to begin with.